# How to create low code based workflow setup in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-flow, lowcode

I want to create a workflow automation where an activity comes in and user can setup a multilevel workflow.

For frontend i am using https://reactflow.dev

How to structure things in nodejs backend. Things like database, accessing control flow statements, statements which requires crons.

[image: workflow]

Comment: This is a very broad question, and also kind of the essence of 'software engineering'. I don't think Stackoverflow is the right place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: You also may want to have a look at node-red. Which doesn't look as fancy, but it's basically a finished product that does exactly that. There's a set of built-in nodes. You can develop your own nodes, or import 3rd party ones. You can also just create a node with javascript or typescript code in it, on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You also may want to have a look at [node-red](https://nodered.org/).

It's an open-source product that does exactly that.

- There's a set of built-in nodes.
- You can develop your own nodes, or import 3rd party ones. Which are stored in NPM.
- You can also just create a node with javascript or typescript code in it, on the fly.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I built mlblocks.com that uses a node based orchestration on the backend, similar to what you're trying to do.

I use reactflow on the front end as well but the backend is a python endpoint and fully custom. I use the networkx library in python for graph traversing like topological sorts and stuff but other than that it's really up to how you pass data between nodes, parallelize the execution of nodes etc.